# I'm android Problems to convert a full name of a android.widget.EditText@410e5a58 edittextview

Tags: java, android

I'm android Problems to convert a full name of a android.widget.EditText@410e5a58 edittextview is the string representation of your EditText object (ie , calling the toString your EditText object will return this string) I know it's simple but , as I followed here Tips site and not getting hit.

coding page1 send to page2

```
TextView codigo1  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView codigo2  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("codigo1",""+codigo1 );
intent.putExtra("codigo2",""+codigo2 );
startActivity(intent);
```

XML page1

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number" >


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Código Monitorado:"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

coding page2 recive

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String codigo1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("codigo1");
    String codigo2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("codigo2");

    TextView codMonitorTV    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCod1);
    TextView codMonitoradoTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCod2);

    codMonitorTV.setText(codigomonitor);
    codMonitoradoTV.setText(codigomonitorado);
```

XML page2

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCodMonitor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/retrieve_location_button"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCodMonitorado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCodMonitor"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/retrieve_location_button"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I type in 1234 and get android.widget.EditText@410e5a58

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `editText.getText().toString()` to get the text input.

**Also it's good to know:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

> public String toString()
>   Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>   The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```
>
> Returns: a string representation of the object.

Comment: Why the additional `toString`?

Comment: `editText.getText()` returns an Editable, that may be not suitable to use in many cases that expects Strings. It can be omitted in a `textView.setText()`.